# How to burn the iso with wodim?

Tags: burning

```
root@localhost:/home/debian# wodim -scanbus
scsibus0:
    0,0,0     0) 'ATA     ' 'MAXTOR STM316081' '3.AA' Disk
    0,1,0     1) *
    0,2,0     2) *
    0,3,0     3) *
    0,4,0     4) *
    0,5,0     5) *
    0,6,0     6) *
    0,7,0     7) *
scsibus1:
    1,0,0   100) 'DVD-16X ' 'DVD-ROM BDV316G ' 'C007' Removable CD-ROM
    1,1,0   101) *
    1,2,0   102) *
    1,3,0   103) *
    1,4,0   104) *
    1,5,0   105) *
    1,6,0   106) *
    1,7,0   107) *
```

How to write the wodim command?

```
wodim -v speed=12  dev=/dev/cdrw  -data  /home/test.iso
```

It don't work in the situation.

```
root@localhost:/home/debian# wodim -v   -data  /home/test.isowodim: No write mode specified.
wodim: Assuming -tao mode.
wodim: Future versions of wodim may have different drive dependent defaults.
TOC Type: 1 = CD-ROM
Device was not specified. Trying to find an appropriate drive...
Using /dev/cdrom of unknown capabilities
scsidev: '/dev/cdrom'
devname: '/dev/cdrom'
scsibus: -2 target: -2 lun: -2
Linux sg driver version: 3.5.27
Wodim version: 1.1.11
Driveropts: 'burnfree'
SCSI buffer size: 64512
Device type    : Removable CD-ROM
Version        : 5
Response Format: 2
Capabilities   : 
Vendor_info    : 'DVD-16X '
Identification : 'DVD-ROM BDV316G '
Revision       : 'C007'
Device seems to be: Generic mmc2 DVD-ROM.
Current: 0x0008 (CD-ROM)
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM) 
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM) (current)
wodim: Sorry, no CD/DVD-Recorder or unsupported CD/DVD-Recorder found on this target.
```

Comment: BDV316G looks like a DVD-ROM drive.  I don't think it possible to burn any disc with it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: As yaegashi pointed out, it seems you don't have a cd/dvd burner. But in case, you have this normally works:

`wodim -v FILE.iso`

The `-v` gives more information like progress indication.